# Is it possible to secure cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery.cookies to manage cookies. I am storing objects and user/login informations.

Is there a way to encrypt or secure the cookies? or is it possible with SSL only?

Comment: Maybe with something like [crypto.js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/). However JavaScript must be turned on otherwise it can't be used

Comment: The only thing I can think of is encrypting the data in the cookie. But this has to be done on the server-side for it to be secure. Encrypting on the client side is probably as insecure as just saving it as plain/text. Since the hacker will probably just reverse the process knowing all the variables.

Comment: @Haris: No, with Javascript and JQuery

Comment: nice link:- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/12/cookies-and-security/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual way to secure cookies is by storing nothing but a randomly-generated session-id in them. The server keeps all sensitive information and associates them to the IDs it assigned to each visitor. This also has the advantage that you can store as much information as you want and are not bound to the space restriction of cookies.

This, of course, can not be done with Javascript alone. You will need server-sided programming for that.

Comment: Thats a good idea, I ll test something like that now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can simply store them as encrypted strings and once you retreive them then decrypt them. Any encryption with your secret key will do

Comment: With the secret key stored somewhere in JavaScript?

Comment: @Vury SO definitely needs to introduce a 'same time poster buddy' badge

Comment: Nopes, in server side script. Remember he mentioned that he is storing username and password, so it would be like axing one's own foot if he puts those values in a javascript variable or sets them via jquery unencrypted on server end first

Comment: @HankyPanky My previous comment should be taken with a pinch of salt ;-) Actually I was thinking the same with the crypto.js that I proposed  to OP to look at, as he asked for a jQuery/JavaScript solution. I think the only possible way is to do the encryption and decryption on server side.

Comment: How is that more secure than plain text? If someone is able to sniff your cookie, they will still be able to use it. The ONLY way to secure it is to use SSL to transmit the cookie in the first place.

Comment: Cookies shouldnt be used, in my opinion, for anything that secure anyways

Answer (score 2):

Create a cookie with all available options along with the `secure` option.

```
$.cookie('myCookie', 'myValue', { expires: 365, secure: true });
```

`secure {Boolean}` If true, the secure attribute of the cookie will be set and the cookie transmission will require a secure protocol (like HTTPS).